# Can I edit a Visual Studio 2008 project in 2010 while keeping it a 2008 only project?

Tags: c#, .net

So on my computer I only have Visual Studio 2010 Express. I need to edit a Visual Studio 2008 project, however it needs to be kept in C# 3.5.

Before I open it in 2010 and accidentally upgrade it, will it be kept in 2008 or C#3.5 format?

I realize I wont be able to use .Net 2010 features, so thats no problem. I just want to make sure if I save my 2008 project using 2010 I will still be able to open it in 2008 and it will work fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The target framework of the project is independent of the solution format. That is, you can convert your project to Visual Studio 2010 and still target the 3.5 Framework. But, once it's converted to 2010, you will not be able to open it in 2008.

Comment: So do I NEED to convert it to 2010 in order to open it in 2010? Or can I leave it as is for 2008? Or is conversion automatic?

Comment: @Tonnie - if you open the project in 2010 it will get automatically converted. You won't be able to open the project in 2008.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot open a project in VS2010 without it being upgraded. The Framework version can be controlled independently, so you can still target 3.5.

The changes to the project/solution files to use 2010 (assuming you don't use any newer features) are fairly minimal, so there may be mileage in just not committing the project/solution files (you can probably achieve this by dropping an ignore file for your source control provider in your local folder, including adding the ignore file to itself, so that doesn't get committed).

If you're mostly editing code (and not often changing the projects in the solution, or files in the projects) you could also have two copies of the files, one for each version, until you can commit to 2010 everywhere (and with Express for free, you might be able to do this quickly?).

Answer (score 2):

No, VS2010 will convert the VS2008 project file.  After it is converted, VS2008 can no longer open it.  There are ways to hack around this, the simple solution is to just use VS2010 consistently.  Next best thing is to only check-in the source code changes.  Next best thing is to give the 2010 project a different name and maintain them both, at least for now.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. Once it's upgraded, it stays that way. There is no official way to downgrade it either. The main driver behind this fact is because of the compiler. Even if you stay in .NET Framework 3.5, you can still use C# 4.0 features (like optional / named parameters) since 2010 will always use the 4.0 compiler.

Imagine a situation where it stayed in a 2008 format but you used a C# 4.0 language feature. Since VS 2008 always uses the C# 3.0 compiler, whenever you open it in 2008, it will no longer compile. This is a good reason to avoid work-arounds that have been posted for downgrading - you get mixed compiler features that can break things pretty easily.

Comment: Isn't it little funny of Microsoft that they (in most simple cases) just change a few lines of codes in the SLN/SOU files, which make the solution/project 'permamently' unreadable for VS2008? You just have to open the project and do the convert, without any interaction with the vs2010 interface or convert to .net 4.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be hard pressed to accidentally upgrade it.  When you open a VS2008 project in VS2010, it automatically starts the upgrade wizard, and you have to decide whether to let it do the upgrade, including making a decision whether to let it take a backup before it does the upgrade.

You can't open a VS2008 project in VS2010 and work on it without upgrading it to VS2010 format first.  And once you've allowed VS2010 to upgrade it, you won't be able to open it in VS2008 any more.

Careful though - don't confuse the version of the framework you want to target, with the version of VS that you're using.

You can target framework 3.5 with VS2010.

There are hacks that let you open VS2010-upgraded projects in VS2008, but it's not a great plan to go down that road (guess how I know).

Answer (score 1):

I was on a seminar where they took this (short of classic?) accident as a sample for versioning. They get a 2008 project from git and start it in vs 2010.

Did the upgrade process and then "ops,  i can't revert the upgrade". They commited the vs2010 converted files to a branch in GIT. When they "came home again", merged the changes in project together with 2008 solution files.

This may not come in touch to you, but the **sense is**:

All files is intact but the solution/project files. So just keep them safe and you can continue use the 2008 version after done your editing in 2010.

Though, without any kind of manual handling of solution/project files - answer (on the  question in your subject) is No!

Comment: There exists some free converters that does the job. Also there exists articles that tells you changing (by notepad) the version in SOU file  from [..10.0] to [..9.0] and things like that. However it includes manual steps and i think that are far more easy just to copy the SOU/SLN files and I think the most safe way is just copy the files and DON'T affect the file structure (add/remove files) while changing between versions).

Answer (score 1):

When you are going to convert it with compatible to 2010 it will ask for the backup...

so... later you can retrieve your file back ...

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but I'm almost sure that project files don't differ between 2008 and 2010 or at least they are compatible. Solution files are a different matter and old solutions do indeed need to be converted. Usually you have few solutions for 2008 and 2010 versions of VS, but they contain the same projects, so the projects don't need to be converted.